# Frontpage blank

Tags: magento-1.9

Warning: include(): Failed opening '`/home/woodstac/public_html/includes/src/Mage_Ultimo_Helper_Cssgen.php' for inclusion (include_path='public_html/includes/src:.:/opt/alt/php55/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php55/usr/share/php')  in /home/woodstac/public_html/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php on line 94`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have call helper which class is not exits.
The code should be:

```
  Mage::helper('ultimo/cssgen')
```

when it emulated as per as magento

`ultimo` is a `helper class prefix` of a `module` .class like: `YourMoudleNameSpace_Ultimo_Helper`and `cssgen` is `file name of class`.

That means final class for  `Mage::helper('ultimo/cssgen')` is `YourMoudleNameSpace_Ultimo_Helper_Cssgen`.

### Issue1: Model prefix is not define properly as per as magento system

```
<global>
....
<helpers>
 <ultimo><!-- called as helper prefix of a module -->
<class>YourMoudleNameSpace_Ultimo_Helper</class>
</ultimo>
</helper>
....
</global>
```

### Issue2:compilation issue:

As per  your question,compiler is `enable` in your system.If `helper class declared properly in config.xml` and class is exits that means you ne`ed to recompile again for copy`  the module properly at `.../includes/src/`

Answer (score 1):

It is obvious that, somewhere in your application, a wrong call to the helper of Ultimo extension is carried out and hence Magento can't figured it out the correct ultimo helper.

This is how a helper call looks like

```
Mage::helper('[ultimo_extension_reference]/cssgen');
```

This `[ultimo_extension_reference]` may be anything and you can find it most probably from `config.xml` file of the extension. Most probably this would be the reason. ie you have used a wrong helper reference name.

Secondly, make sure you have the helper class `Cssgen.php` is defined inside ultimo extension. (You can find all helper class of the extension inside `Helper` directory).

Try to tackle it down using the above information and this error is completely traceable and erasable.